# Powershell save the results GetFileHash within If and else

Tags: powershell

So I am using PowerShell script :
If the path exist then Get me the hash value :

```
$Path = 'c:\exampel\example.text'
if (Test-Path $Path){
Get-FileHash $Path | Format-List
else {
write-Host "File Not found!"}
```

The result is :

> Algorithm : SHA256
> Hash      : 6A785ADC0263238DAB3EB37F4C185C8FBA7FEB5D425D034CA9864F1BE1C192kd
> Path      : c:\exampel\example.text

I tried but the file was not found and there is no result.

```
if (Test-Path $Path){
Get-FileHash $Path | Format-List | export-csv c:\example.csv
```

My question is how can I save the result to a file.txt?

Comment: DO NOT use the `Format-*` cmdlets for anything other than FINAL output to the screen or a plain text file. they wreck your objects by wrapping them in formatting code.

Comment: Hi Lee_ I tried it without Format-list but still the result is wrong  :(

Comment: Now that you know that `Format-List` shouldn't be used, please update your question to remove it and describe _in what way_ the result is still wrong.

Comment: @AbdalazizAlharthi - as mklement0 mentioned, please remove the no-longer-part-of-the-problem `F-L` cmdlet from your Question. [*grin*] ///// also as mklement0 mentioned ... we need to know what you ARE getting in your exported data.  please add that to your Question so folks can find it ... and wrap it in code formatting so that it will be easy to read. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71767927/powershell-save-the-results-getfilehash-within-if-and-else/71768652#comment126828938_71767927) commented, **never** use `Format-*` cmdlets if you want to process the data any further (like saving it in a CSV in this case).

`Format-*` cmdlets are for **display purposes ONLY** and will mess up your original data.

Try

```
$Path = 'c:\exampel\example.text'
if (Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Leaf) {
    Get-FileHash -Path $Path | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\example.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
else { Write-Host "File Not found!"}
```

The resulting CSV file, when opened in notepad should then look like

```
"Algorithm","Hash","Path"
"SHA256","6A785ADC0263238DAB3EB37F4C185C8FBA7FEB5D425D034CA9864F1BE1C192kd","C:\exampel\example.text"
```

---

if you need to do this on a series of file paths you read from a text file, do:

```
# change the path to your text file
$allFiles = Get-Content -Path 'X:\somewhere\filepaths.txt'
# loop over the paths
$result = foreach ($Path in $allFiles) {
    if (Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Leaf) {
        # output the object so it gets collected in variable $result
        Get-FileHash -Path $Path
    }
    else { 
        Write-Host "File '$Path' Not found"
    }
}
# now save the results in your csv
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\example.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks Theo it worked fine but there are more than 1 path , and the csv only saved 1 hash value

Comment: @AbdalazizAlharthi Sure, that should be no problem, just tell me how you obtain these paths. Form a text file or something?

Comment: Yes the paths from a txt file

Comment: @AbdalazizAlharthi Please see my edit